# Why is the sequence exact?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homological-algebra, exact-sequence

Bredon states:

> For $A \subset X$, the sequence
>
> $$ 0 \rightarrow \Delta_{*}(A) \otimes G \rightarrow \Delta_{*}(X) \otimes G \rightarrow \Delta_{*}(X,A) \otimes G \rightarrow 0$$
>
> is exact because of the splitting map $\Delta_{*}(X,A) \rightarrow \Delta_{*}(X)$

I think that everything can be proved directly (without using the splitting map), except for the exactness at the center. Hence, I think we must use the splitting map to prove that, but I can't pinpoint how. How to proceed?

Comment: Tensoring is right exact, so you will be able to probe exactness of the middle and right terms without using the splitting map. You will need it to show exactness of the left term. I think the author phrased this sentence a little poorly: really what you're using is the splitting map $\Delta_*(X) \to \Delta_*(A)$, but the existence of this is equivalent to the splitting map the author mentions.

Comment: This is essentially a duplicate of [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1542414/10014) -- the only thing you need is that $\Delta_i(\text{something})$ is free abelian. This implies here that $\Delta_i(X)$ is projective, hence the splitting map exists and you can prove exactness, but it follows from general theorems (projective modules are flat).

Comment: @NajibIdrissi Yes, Bredon mentions that the fact that $\Delta_{*}$ is free abelian implies the sequence is split, and hence that the splitting map I mentioned exists. But your answer in the question you linked seems circular to me... you say that the result follows due to the fact that a free abelian group is flat... but in the linked wikipedia article, a flat module is something that preserves exactness through tensoring... which is what I'm trying to prove, essentially (it's actually more general).

Comment: It's not circular, once you've proven that a free module is flat, you're done -- the question has actually nothing to do with topology. If I understand correctly your comment, you understand that and you're just looking for a proof that a free module is flat?

Comment: @NajibIdrissi Yes, I think so. I would like such proof for terms of generality, but I think that in this special case (with these special maps) there are things which can be simplified. For instance, Alex says that I would need the splitting for the left term, but the left term is an inclusion, hence the exactness is clear (or isn't it?).

Comment: Here's an alternative argument for why the first map $\Delta_*(A)\otimes G\to \Delta_*(X)\otimes G$ is injective: Let's denote the map $\Delta_*(A)\to \Delta_*(X)$ by $i$. The existence of a splitting map $\Delta_{*}(X,A) \rightarrow \Delta_{*}(X)$ is equivalent to the existence of a retraction $r:\Delta_*(X)\to \Delta_*(A)$, that is, a map $r$ satisfying $r\circ i=id$. Then apply the $-\otimes G$ functor and by functoriality, the map induced by $r$ is still a left-inverse to the map induced by $i$, hence the claim.

Comment: (Exactness in all other spots follows from the fact that $-\otimes G$ is right-exact, as Alex already pointed out.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Proving that free modules are flat (without appealing projective modules)](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/407417/proving-that-free-modules-are-flat-without-appealing-projective-modules)

Comment: @NajibIdrissi: The fact that free modules are flat is not particularly relevant here, because you're tensoring with $G$, not with a free module (though you can use the fact that free modules are flat by looking at the long exact Tor sequence).  All that's going on here is the fact that split exact sequences are preserved by any additive functor.

Comment: @EricWofsey Could you please elaborate in an answer?

Comment: @EricWofsey Well yes, the statement you wrote in parenthesis is exactly why free modules being flat is relevant... If $A$ is flat, tensoring an exact sequence $0 \to A \to B \to C \to 0$ with anything will still remain exact.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

More generally, if $F:Ab\to Ab$ is any functor which preserves addition of maps, then it sends split exact sequences to split exact sequences.  This follows from the following theorem:

> **Theorem** Let $A\stackrel{i}{\to} B\stackrel{p}{\to} C$ be a pair of maps of abelian groups.  Then the following are equivalent:
>
> 1. There exist maps $q:B\to A$ and $j:C\to B$ such that $qi=1$, $pj=1$, and $iq+jp=1$.
> 2. The sequence $0\to A\to B\to C\to 0$ is exact, and there exists a map $q:B\to A$ such that $qi=1$.
> 3. The sequence $0\to A\to B\to C\to 0$ is exact, and there exists a map $j:C\to B$ such that $pj=1$.
> 4. There exists an isomorphism $f:B\to A\oplus C$ such that $fi:A\to A\oplus C$ is the inclusion map $a\mapsto (a,0)$ and $pf^{-1}:A\oplus C\to C$ is the projection map $(a,c)\mapsto c$.

*Proof:* Let us prove $4\Rightarrow 3\Rightarrow 2\Rightarrow 1\Rightarrow 4$.

($4\Rightarrow 3$): It is easy to see the sequence is exact.  To get $j$, compose the inclusion $C\to A\oplus C$ with $f^{-1}$.

($3\Rightarrow 2$): For $b\in B$, let $\tilde{q}(b)=b-j(p(b))$.  Then $p(\tilde{q}(b))=p(b)-p(j(p(b)))=p(b)-p(b)=0$, so $\tilde{q}(b)\in \ker(p)$.  Since $0\to A\to B\to C$ is exact, there is a unique element $q(b)\in A$ such that $i(q(b))=\tilde{q}(b)$, and $q:B\to A$ is a homomorphism.  Furthermore, if $a\in A$, then $\tilde{q}(i(a))=i(a)-j(p(i(a)))=i(a)$ since $pi=0$, so $qi=1$.

($2\Rightarrow 1$): Given $c\in C$, choose a $b\in B$ such that $p(b)=c$, and let $j(c)=b-i(q(b))$.  This does not depend on the choice of $b$ since any other choice is of the form $b+i(a)$ for some $a\in A$, and $i(q(i(a)))=i(a)$.  This defines a homomorphism $j:C\to B$, and $p(j(c))=p(b)-p(i(q(b)))=p(b)=c$, so $pj=1$.  It is also immediate from the definition of $j$ that $iq+jp=1$.

($1\Rightarrow 4$):  First, note that $pi=p(iq+jp)i=piqi+pjpi=pi+pi$, so $pi=0$.  Similarly, $qj=0$.  Now define $f:B\to A\oplus C$ by $f(b)=(q(b),p(b))$ and $g:A\oplus C\to B$ by $g(a,c)=i(a)+j(c)$.  The fact that $f$ and $g$ are inverse and that $fi$ and $pg$ have the desired form follows immediately from the identities $qi=1$, $pj=1$, $pi=0$, $qj=0$, and $iq+jp=1$.

If these conditions hold, the sequence $0\to A\to B\to C\to 0$ is called *split exact*.  In particular, condition (1) is manifestly preserved by any functor $F:Ab\to Ab$ which preserves addition of maps, so such a functor preserves all the other conditions as well.  In your case, $F$ is the functor $-\otimes G$, and you have a sequence that you know satisfies (3).  It follows that the sequence obtained by applying $F$ still satisfies (3), and in particular is exact.